# male cat wanting me to follow him

Tags: cats

My male cat, who never meows, has been coming to me, screaming at me, and going through the hole in the floor behind the dryer. The hole leads to under the trailer. he did it again tonight and I opened the door for him to go outside, just for him to come back in through the hole and start screaming again. what could this be? the back yard and under the trailer is basically a swamp so it will be hard for us to get under there. He is around a year old.

Comment: can you please try to add more information to your question,any other cats living  in the area,is your cat neutered,what wildlife is in the area,your general location,for how long has the meowing lasted hour or days? please edit anything you can add into your question.

Comment: questions like this are hard to answer but if you can add information that makes it answerable the question can be reopened,or you can answer the question yourself if you discover what your cat want.